# Postgres epoch extract begining and end of last month

Tags: postgresql, time, epoch

I need to find in postgres number of rows from table history, where date in clock column is from previous month (clock is stored as epoch timestamp).
First i did:

```
select count(clock) from history where 
date_trunc('month',to_timestamp(clock)) = date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 month';
```

But this is very slow. I was thinking i would be quicker if i did something like this:

```
select count(clock) from history 
where clock between {extracted first second of previous month} and {extracted last second of previous month};
```

When i put values by hand, is much quicker (I have index on clock). But I don't know how extract first, and last second of the previous month.
Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start of the previous month as a timestamp is:

```
date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - interval '1' month
```

If you avoid the `between` operator, you don't need calculate the "last second" of the previous month but only the start of the current month:

```
select count(clock) 
from history 
where clock >= extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - interval '1' month)
  and clock < extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_timestamp));
```

Note the `<` operator instead of `<=`

Comment: Thank you!!!! It's so simple, and I tried to figure it out for 3 hour :)